# compare if date is same in mysql where clause

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.username = :user AND date_format(t2.date, 'Y-m-d') == :time");
$stmt->bindValue(':time', date_format($time, 'Y-m-d'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I have this code to check if the date is equal. By equal means **SAME DAY** like `January 1, 1990 == January 1, 1990`

But I am getting `date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,`

What is the appropriate way to compare date if same day in mysql where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql **str_to_date**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.username = :user AND str_to_date(t2.date,'%M %d, %Y')  == :time");
$stmt->bindValue(':time', str_to_date($time,'%M %d, %Y'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```